# My_list.extend([My_list.pop(), my_list.pop])

Tags: python, python-3.x

***My code:***

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
my_list.extend([my_list.pop(), my_list.pop(), my_list.pop()])
```

So when I print it the result is

```
[1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
```

so why this Skew the last three Elements

Comment: `my_list=[1,2,3,4,5]` at initially, after 1st pop `my_list=[1,2,3,4]` and `5` is returned, after 2nd pop `my_list=[1,2,3]` and 4 is returned and after 3rd pop `my_list=[1,2]` and `3` is returned. Now you `my_list.extend([5,4,3])` which makes `my_list=[1,2,5,4,3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Python's order of execution is inside-out and left-to-right.

So here python fill first pop() three elements from `my_list` and create a list from those, left to right -> `[5, 4, 3]` then it will execute `extend` appending everything front-to-back.

Essentially what your code does is:

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
second = []
second.append(my_list.pop())
second.append(my_list.pop())
second.append(my_list.pop())
my_list.extend(second)
```